# Laravel Service Provider “Unresolvable dependency”

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I am having an issue that seems to be fairly common across the interwebs, but I'm afraid I can't pinpoint the solution.

### Error

```
BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 888:
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $app ]] in class Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider
```

### Service Provider (Providers/SocialAccountServiceProvider.php)

Here is my relatively simple service provider.

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\User;
use Socialite;
use App\SocialAccount;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class SocialAccountServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $socialNetwork = '';

    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    public function resolveTwitterUser()
    {
        $this->socialNetwork = 'twitter';

        return $this->resolveUser();
    }

    public function resolveFacebookUser()
    {
        $this->socialNetwork = 'facebook';

        return $this->resolveUser();
    }

    public function resolveUser()
    {
        return $resolvedUser;
    }
}
```

### Registration (config/app.php)

And I have registered the service provider with the app like so.

```
App\Providers\SocialAccountServiceProvider::class,
```

### Controller (Controllers/TwitterAuthController.php)

My controller is quite simple as well.

```
use App\User;
use Socialite;
use App\SocialAccount;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Providers\SocialAccountServiceProvider;

class TwitterAuthController extends Controller
{
    public function redirect()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('twitter')->redirect();
    }

    public function callback(SocialAccountServiceProvider $account)
    {
        $user = $account->resolveTwitterUser();

        if (Auth::loginUsingId($user->id, true))
            return redirect()->to('/');
        else
            return redirect()->to('/login');
    }
}
```

*Would any kind souls be willing to help?*

Deets:
- `Laravel: 5.4`
- `Socialite: 3.0`

Comment: I am not sure if service providers are supposed to be injected to controller that way. They should register staff only.

Comment: Register staff?

Comment: Stuff :P When you look at documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/providers and ready service providers https://github.com/laravel/socialite/blob/3.0/src/SocialiteServiceProvider.php you will see it registers classes that should be injected in controllers so you should not inject service provider itself.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Thanks for the clarification.